# Can I use rattle on 64-bit R?

Tags: r, 64-bit, package, data-mining

Trying to install `rattle` on a windows server 2008 R2 64bit machine, using 64-bit R ver2.11, I got the following message:

```
install.packages("rattle", dependencies=TRUE)
Warning: dependencies ‘RGtk2’, ‘rggobi’, ‘RSvgDevice’, ‘Biobase’, ‘multicore’, ‘marray’, ‘affy’, ‘snowFT’, ‘Rmpi’, ‘rpvm’ are not available
```

When I tried to install one of them:

```
install.packages("RGtk2")
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘RGtk2’ is not available
```

Finally I noticed [this](http://www.cran.r-project.org/bin/windows64/contrib/2.11/@ReadMe) and [this](http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Can-I-use-R-on-64_002dbit-Windows_003f). Should I go back to 32-bit R in order to use rattle?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use Revolution R for Windowswith Rattle, was told currently RGtk2 is not available on 64 bit, but the next release (in April or so) will support it

Answer (score 1):

Why not 64-bit Linux?

Comment: What if I don't have an option?

Comment: You didn't say so how are we to know?  Rattle can be difficult to install because of RGtk2 which has a number of dependencies. So work on porting that to win64 and all will be good.  In the meantime, you have the alternative of using R on 64-bit Linux / Unix which has been around for a decade.  You may also have an alternative with Revolution and their commercial 64-bit Windows.